# URL rewrite IIS 7.0 with querystring

Tags: model-view-controller, url-rewriting

i have an mvc site and i am trying to redirect the url from old one with querystring to new one and i have following rule in web.config

```
<rule name="redirect boy bedding" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="baby-sets" ignoreCase="true"/>
          <conditions>
            <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="parameters=4DB23699-69F4-46C9-AA0A-E2D5E138459C" matchType="Pattern"></add>
          </conditions>
          <action type="Redirect" url="/baby-sets" redirectType="Permanent"/>
        </rule>
```

but with this rule i am always getting

[image]

i just want to redirect from this url

http://localhost:49970/baby-sets?parameters=4DB23699-69F4-46C9-AA0A-E2D5E138459C

to

http://localhost:49970/baby-sets

please help to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

i figured out and changed to this

```
<rule name="redirect boy bedding" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="baby-sets"/>
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
            <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="parameters=4DB23699-69F4-46C9-AA0A-E2D5E138459C"/>
          </conditions>
          <action type="Redirect" url="baby-sets" appendQueryString="false" redirectType="Permanent"/>
        </rule>
```